# Project a Sequence on a Set

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I am reading [this paper](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/tds/papers/Lynch/TM-486.pdf) and looking at Section 2.1:

If $\sigma$ is a sequence over $K$ and $L \subseteq K$, then $\sigma \lceil L$ denotes the sequence obtained by projecting $\sigma$ on $L$.

What exactly does "projecting $\sigma$ on $L$" mean? I've never encountered this set notation before.

Comment: $\sigma\lceil L$ appears to be the sequence obtained from $\sigma$ by dropping out all elements of $K\setminus L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian Scott wrote, the answer is that

"$\sigma \lceil L$ appears to be the sequence obtained from $\sigma$ by dropping out all elements of $K  \backslash  L$."